Resize div's scroll bar to fit beveled corners
Really simple. How can I offset where the top and bottom of my scroll bar lie? It currently isn't playing nicely with the beveled corners.
Here's what it looks like right now.

I'm hoping it's a simple resize thing but I don't know how easy that is. Can I do it without javascript?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

If you separate your border element and the scrollable element, you can use padding on the border element:


.bordered {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding-block: 2rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
.scrollable {
  max-height: 80dvh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#content {
  height: 200dvh;
}
<div class="bordered">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>




This might solve the issue by using clip-path for the body
 body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 20px) 0, 100% 20px, 100% 100%, 20px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 20px));
 }


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
